# Reassign global variables locally without changing them in the global scope. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I know how i can make my code work as intended, but i tried to use the same variable names and bumped into the following question:

Is it possible to reassign min and max variables inside submitSettings() so that in the global scope they remain untouched?
(You can see in the code why i wanted them to remain unchanged in the global scope.)

If yes, please tell me how and where can i learn more about this topic.

```
  // here i get the HTML elements from <input>.
  let min = document.getElementById('min')
  let max = document.getElementById('max')

  function submitSettings() {
    // here i want to validate the values from those HTML elements while maintaining the same variable names (min, max).
    function validateSettings() {
      min = min.valueAsNumber // My question: How can i reassign global variables locally without changing them in global scope?
      let max = max.valueAsNumber // Or: How can i get max variable from the scope from outside (from global scope)?

      min >= max ? console.log("Not good") : console.log("OK")
    }

    validateSettings()

    // here i want to clear <input>, but i can't because min and max are not HTML elements anymore, rather numbers.
    min.value = ''
    max.value = ''
  }
```

Comment: Since there in different scopes, you can use `let min` and `let max` again. Not sure if that is what your asking for though...

Comment: I know i can use different variables. It is more an educational question. I want to understand scopes, this, ... in the examples i encounter

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Answer (score 1):

Shadowing variables is generally considered bad practice, for the reasons your code highlights. It is difficult to maintain the scope from one to next. There are different ways of getting around this, but they mostly rely on renaming the variable for the local context.

```
// here i get the HTML elements from <input>.
  const min = document.getElementById('min')
  const max = document.getElementById('max')

  function submitSettings() {
    // here i want to validate the values from those HTML elements while maintaining the same variable names (min, max).
    function validateSettings() {
      let minValue = min.valueAsNumber // My question: How can i reassign global variables locally without changing them in global scope?
      let maxValue = max.valueAsNumber // Or: How can i get max variable from the scope from outside (from global scope)?

      minValue >= maxValue ? console.log("Not good") : console.log("OK")
    }

    validateSettings()


    min.value = ''
    max.value = ''
  }
```

Strictly speaking, the `let` keyword is unique in that it creates block scoped variables, so the following would be allowed

```
const global = 1;
const local = () => {
  let global = 2;
  console.log(global);
}

local(); // logs 2
console.log(global); // logs 1
```

But I don't think it is very good practice

You could also use the fact that `validateSettings` is a function and make `min` and `max` arguments to it.

```
// here i get the HTML elements from <input>.
  const min = document.getElementById('min')
  const max = document.getElementById('max')

  function submitSettings() {
    // here i want to validate the values from those HTML elements while maintaining the same variable names (min, max).
    function validateSettings(min, max) {    
      min >= max ? console.log("Not good") : console.log("OK")
    }

    validateSettings(min.value, max.value)


    min.value = ''
    max.value = ''
  }
```

Comment: But if you don't use shadowing you could end up with lots of different names for the same idea/variable ex: min, myMin, minim...?

Comment: You may end up with some but usually you can split code between files and avoid most of that. If it's a bigger issue you can follow the second example and use the `let` keyword to redefine a local version of the same variable. Just know however, that you cannot access the global variable in that scope again.

Comment: I added one more example showing how you can take advantage of the fact that `validateSettings` is a function to do what you want.

Comment: That's neat :) Thanks